# nftables won't load rules at boot

Tags: fedora, reboot, nftables

On Fedora 37 :

- my *nftables* rules are written in */etc/sysconfig/nftables.conf*
- *iptables.service* could not be found as it is the default in F37
- *nftables.service* and *NetworkManager.service* are enabled

Neithertheless, at reboot *nft list ruleset* is empty.
Isn't it supposed to load them or have I got to create a custom script ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I knew it was a simple trick : firewalld was still enabled ! After disable and mask it : everything is working ! ^^